# Display latest image in directory ending in

Tags: php

I'd like to display the last modified image in a directory that ends in a specific way.

I have it working to display the last file in the directory I only don't know how to go about filtering the result to only display the latest in the directory ending in "wide-block.jpg"

```
<?php
$base_url = 'images/folio/web-portfolio';
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'images/folio/no-image.jpg';
if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
    if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..') && ($latestFile != '.htaccess')) {
       $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
       if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
          $newest_mtime = $mtime;
          $show_file = "$base_url/$latestFile";
       }
    }
  }
}
echo '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Latest from the web">';
?>
```

I got that code from somewhere else and realize it won't need the second if statement of != file types listed once my check of display the latest file ending in "wide-block.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should sort it out for you, basically just add another rule to filter in images ending in your required field.

Basically just use the strpos() function to determine if the value you are looking for is in the file name.

Also wrapped the code within a function, allowing bot the desired folder location, and desired string which the file must end in.

```
<?php
function getLatestImage($folderName, $imageEnding) {
    $newest_mtime = 0;
    $base_url = 'images/folio/'.$folderName;        
    $file_ending = $imageEnding;
    $show_file = 'images/folio/no-image.jpg';
    if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
        while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
            if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..') && ($latestFile != '.htaccess') && (strpos($latestFile, $file_ending))) {
             $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
                if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
                    $newest_mtime = $mtime;
                    $show_file = "$base_url/$latestFile";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $show_file;
}

echo '<img src="' .getLatestImage('foldername', 'file_ending.jpg'). '" alt="Latest from the web">';
?>
```

Comment: That works perfectly... Thanks so much! One change I had to make was I used "strpos" instead of "str_pos" for any one else looking at this. It didn't work as str_pos

Comment: Would there be any way to use this code for multiple folders on the same page without adding redundant code?

Comment: Yes, simply pass the folder name in to the code, as I have done. Then wrap it into a function. Updating the code to reflect this.

Comment: That works, I would have never figured that out on my own. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That is my way, resolving this issue, I am not a programmer, it is try on error product :)

I used it in a wordpress installation and had to install the plugin
**Allow PHP in Posts and Pages**
(thats why the php tags are different, normally  instead of [PHP] [/PHP])

---

```
[PHP]
global $path;    // path to directory has to be global, using it later in html

$dir = "Planetwebcam/";

$files = scandir($dir, 1);                // read directory backkwards

$picture = ($files[0]);                   // get las picture file name

$path = "http://www.yourdomain.ch/Planetwebcam/$picture";

[/PHP]


<a href="[PHP]global $path;echo $path; [/PHP]">
<img class="alignnone size-large" alt="Last picture" src="[PHP]global 
$path;echo $path; [/PHP]" width="1600" height="1200" /></a>
```