# Get latest image from directory

Tags: php, image, file, glob

I was getting my photo from a folder randomly as the code below:

```
$imagesDir = 'tags/chilli_crab/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

How can I change this to get the latest photo instead of the random one?
Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Using db would be highly recommended, but you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12184727/1219200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $images);

$latestimage = $images[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$images = array();
foreach (scandir($folder) as $node) {
    $nodePath = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node;
    if (is_dir($nodePath)) continue;
    $images[$nodePath] = filemtime($nodePath);
}
arsort($images);
$newest = array_slice($images, 0, 5);
```

Hope this one help you