# Display album cover for all photo gallery albums

Tags: php, mysql

I have a photo gallery where I allow the user to create individual photo albums.
I can display the name of each album like this.

```
$album = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `album_id`,`album_date`,`album_title` FROM `albums` ORDER BY `album_date` DESC");
```

What I'm trying to do is add a cover photo for each album, but can't seem to get my query correct.
This is what I'm trying.

```
$album = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT
albums.album_id,
albums.created,
albums.album_date,
albums.album_title,
gallery.file_name,
gallery.id,
gallery.album_id
FROM
albums
INNER JOIN gallery ON gallery.album_id = albums.album_id ORDER BY gallery.id DESC ;");
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I want each album name displayed with the last photo from each album as the cover photo.

If I add a LIMIT of 1 to my query, only one album is shown.

Here are my tables that are Joined together by a Foreign Key.

**Albums Table:**

[image]

**Gallery Table:**

[image]

Any solution to get this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where you have gallery.file_name you probably need to replace this with a subquery to retrieve the image that you want.

Comment: @jeff would you mind showing me an example of how to write a subquery? Don't have to use my query. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SELECT item, (select item from x where y=1 limit 1) from a where s=10. Subqueries can only return a single value.

Comment: Your photo albums are stored in directories right? if so why not choose the last file by the date and time it was created -- similar question here   -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184619/display-latest-image-in-directory-ending-in

Comment: ORDER BY gallery.id AND gallery.id DESC - looks a bit funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the most recent image in each album using the following query:

```
SELECT album_id, MAX(id) id
FROM gallery
GROUP BY album_id
```

Alternatively, you can select a random image in each album like this:

```
SELECT g.album_id, (
    SELECT id FROM gallery g2
    WHERE g2.album_id = g.album_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
) id
FROM gallery g
GROUP BY g.album_id
```

Either of the above queries could be plugged into a complete query:

```
SELECT a.album_id, a.created, a.album_date, a.album_title,
       g.file_name, g.id, g.album_id
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN (
    # above query goes here
) alb_img USING (album_id)
INNER JOIN gallery g ON g.id = alb_img.id
ORDER BY a.album_date DESC;
```

If you'd like to select empty albums as well as those containing one or more images change the INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the help. Question though if I need to orginize the images by Random and I add `ORDER BY g.id RAND () LIMIT 1` that doesn't work. What would I do to get it to work? Thanks again.

Comment: Also the albums are ASC like this: `Album 1, Album 2, Album 3` and the images are DESC. How can I make it so the albums are DESC like `Album 3, Album 2, Album 1` and the images are DESC or RAND()?

Comment: Try to avoid this kind of subquery's. For each row found in albums * for each row found in gallery, the subquery is executed.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate sorting albums by date, and redesigned the query to support optionally selecting a random image in each album. The query should also perform better since it no longer joins on a subquery. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT album_id, album_name, title, COALESCE(file_name, 'mydefaultimage.jpeg') 
  FROM albums
  LEFT JOIN gallery on album_id = album 
  ORDER BY added DESC
  LIMIT 1,1
```

if there's no image, title will be `null` and filename will contain the default image name.

**[EDIT]**
no `,` after the `DESC`

Comment: I tried your method,but gave me errors and displayed nothing. Will try working on it though. Probably a user error lol.

Comment: I tried a couple variations and doesn't seem to be working. I don't understand why I need `'mydefaultimage.jpeg'` ..? I want the cover of each album to be the last uploaded image in each album.

Comment: This query will only return a single row since the LIMIT clause applies to the query as a whole. To work as expected the LIMIT must apply only to the JOIN expression.

The point of COALESCE would be to provide a default image file (rather than `NULL`) for albums without any rows in the left-joined gallery table. Alternatively, an INNER JOIN can be used to only select albums that contain one or more images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    `album`.`album_title`
    , (SELECT file_name FROM gallery WHERE gallery.`album_id` = album.`album_id` ORDER BY file_name DESC LIMIT 1) AS file_name
FROM
    `album`
```

Comment: I created the tables and populated them with the data that you provided. It worked so there must be some other cause for it not to work.

Comment: Could it be there is a relation between the two tables with a Foreign Key? I'm pretty new to Foreign Keys so maybe thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to determine the latest id for the image for each album:

```
SELECT album_id, MAX(id) id FROM gallery GROUP BY album_id
```

You can easily put this as inline view (subquery) in a query

```
SELECT
    a.album_name, g.file_name, g.title
FROM
    (SELECT album_id, MAX(id) id FROM gallery GROUP BY album_id) a
JOIN
    gallery g USING (album_id, id)
JOIN
    albums a USING (album_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
SELECT albums.album_id,
       albums.album_title,
       albums.album_date,
       albums.created,
       gallery.id,
       gallery.file_name
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `gallery` ON (albums.album_id = gallery.album_id)
WHERE gallery.id IN
    ( SELECT MAX(gallery.id)
     FROM `gallery`
     GROUP BY gallery.album_id)
```

**Explanation:**

You first need to select the latest record corresponding to each album from `gallery` table. Group the records with `album_id` field, and user the aggregate function `MAX()` to obtain the record with biggest id in the grouped result.

```
SELECT MAX(gallery.id)
     FROM `gallery`
     GROUP BY gallery.album_id
```

then join the `gallery` table with `albums` table with `LEFT JOIN` and use the results of the above query in `WHERE` clause. You can specify the whole set of fields you need to use in the `SELECT` part of the outer query

```
SELECT albums.album_id,
       albums.album_title,
       albums.album_date,
       albums.created,
       gallery.id,
       gallery.file_name
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `gallery` ON (albums.album_id = gallery.album_id)
WHERE gallery.id IN
    ( FIRSTQUERY....)
```